# PeripheralManager.getInstance() throws NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: raspberry-pi, android-things

Raspberry Pi w/ Android Things

I'm compiling with 0.7-devpreview and using the new PeripheralManager.getInstance(), but got NoClassDefFoundError:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/things/pio/PeripheralManager;

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I noticed that androidthings dependency is documented as compileOnly, so probably a directly call into the OS. Upgraded OS to 0.7 dev preview and problem solved.